# Infinite Recursion with Spies in Angular Unit Testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, recursion, karma-jasmine

New to unit testing here.

I have a situation where the function I am testing `getFolderTree$()` recursively calls another function `getFolderChildren$()`. I tried setting up a spy for `getFolderChildren$()` as seen in the below attempt at a unit test. However, this results in `getFolderTree$()` never getting the chance to hit the base case because it keeps getting more and more children and a maximum call stack size exceeded error.

When I set the `getFolderChildren$()` spyOn to return an empty array, I solve the recursion issue but I can't cover the lines that deal with children.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue and still get full coverage of the original function? Any help appreciated!

**Original Function**

```
getFolderTree$(tenantId: number, folderId: number): Observable<FolderTree> {
  return combineLatest([
    this.getFolder$(tenantId, folderId),
    this.getFolderChildren$(tenantId, folderId)]).pipe(
      map(([folder, subFolders]) => ({
        parent: { name: folder.folderName, id: folder.id, description: folder.description, children: [] } as FolderTree,
        childFolders: subFolders
      })),
      mergeMap(data => forkJoin([
        of(data.parent),
        ...data.childFolders.map(child => this.getFolderTree$(child.tenantId, child.id))
      ])),
      map(([parent, ...children]) => { parent.children = children.sort(this.sortByFolderName); return parent; })
    );
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
it('should get folder tree', () => {
        let folder = {id: 1, tenantId: tenantID, folderName: 'some folder'} as IFolder;
        let subFolders = [{id: 2, tenantId: tenantID, folderName: 'some child folder'} as IFolder];

        spyOn(folderService, 'getFolder$').and.returnValue(of(folder));
        spyOn(folderService, 'getFolderChildren$').and.returnValue(of(subFolders));

        let result = folderService.getFolderTree$(tenantID, folderID);
        result.subscribe(value => {
            //expectation here
        });
    });
```

Comment: use `and.callFake(yourCustomLogic)` to return different results depending of parameters

Comment: I establish the SpyOn before I ever call getFolderTree$() so how would I specify I first want a child returned and then want an empty array?

Comment: `and.callFake((tenId, nodeId) => nodeId == 1 ? subFolders : [])`